# Style of Controle At various Event

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Could anyone tell what would be the **style** of the **Label** or **Button** at various event  shows in the below image.

**1. MouseOver**

[image]

**2 MousePressed** and **Control Selected**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at [Style triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers.aspx). To figure out what properties you need you can have a look at the [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590083.aspx).

For example it can be something like:

```
<Style x:Key="Triggers" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
        <Setter Property = "Background" Value="LightGray"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter Property = "BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
        <Setter Property = "BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
    </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The above style does not recreate the look of the button from the image, it's just a sample on how it can be done.

You can have a look at the [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx) class to see what properties you can change.

Comment: @Faciu, thank you so much for answering, but,, not found any property like `BorderColor` for button

Comment: @Aryan sorry for that, it's BorderBrush, i've also updated the sample code

Comment: @Faciu, ok thank you so much...BTW,,is there any way in XAML not to write any code in code Behind that suppose `MouseEnter` event of `LABEL` is fire and we can change the `background` of Label..just only using XAML...Thanks....

Comment: @Aryan, same thing as in this case. Write a style targeting a Label with a trigger for IsMouseOver and change the Background property to what color you need.

Comment: @Faciu,..ya but `IsMouseOver` property is not available for `Label` so i decided to use `MouseEnter` event of Label and Changing the `BackGround` property of `Lable` but i stuck up that how to handle events in `XAML` and set appropriate property of control??.....thanks......

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question properly, I think you can change the opacity on MousePressed and Mouseover events.